# User input for parameters for different functions [Python]

Tags: python, input, parameters

I am pretty sure there is, but is there a concise way to ask for user input and pass this to defined functions as arguments, if those functions differ from each other in accepted arguments?

It is easy to write a separate function for each function that handles user input for each function that takes arguments, but I am pretty sure there is a neater/conciser way to do this. Does anyone have a hint perhaps?

For example:

```
def choice_menu():
    """function that ideally handles user input for ALL other functions"""
    choice = input(">")
    try:
        if: choice == :
            #some_function(some_parameter); this differs per function that is to be called

        elif: choice == :
            #some_function(another_parameter); this differs per function that is to be called
    except:
        #choice is not an accepted argument; this differs per function that is to be called

def some_function(parameter=1):
    """parameter: takes 1 or 2, default=1"""

def some_other_function(parameter='some string'):
    """parameter: takes 1, 2, and 'some string', default='some string')"""
```

I have used Python's built-in [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) to create a (default) settings.ini file, and the plan is to replace the settings based on user input and then calling functions from the (changed) .ini file. But if there are better options, please let me know!

Thank you :)

Comment: im not sure if this is what you're going for, but `some_function(input())` ... ?

Comment: This looks like a good idea, thank you!